# XPages DynamicViewPanel: expand categories by default

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

The Dynamic view panel control does not have the "ExpandLevel" property so how get the views displayed in that control expanded by default?

As usual, thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ExpandLevel property in the 'data' properties (All properties tab).

`Data > data > expandLevel` property:

[image: Data>data>expandLevel property]